# Why is length of array not displaying in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, return

Code:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.todos = [
      {id: 100, text: 'Rich'},
      {id: 200, text: 'Dave'}
    ];
  },



activeTodos: function() {
    this.todos = this.todos.length(function() {
      return this.todos;
    });
    this.emitChange();
  }



<p>Todo's Remaining: {this.activeTodos} </p>




activeItems: function(){
    this.context.executeAction(activeToDosAction);
  },
```

Explanation:

I am trying to print out the size of the array to the browser window (this can be seen in the `<p>` tags within the code). So far nothing is displaying and I cant figure out why. `activeTodos` should be calling the length of `todos`.

i can post more code if people require it. i am using reactjs hence the { }  brackets within HTML

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of weird things there. If you only need to display the length of `this.todos` you can do something like this:

`<p>Todo's Remaining: {this.todos.length} </p>`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you pass a function to length. That is not required.

Your code should work if you change it to:

```
activeTodos: function() {
  return this.todos.length;
}
```

I'm not sure what your function emitChange should be doing, so I omitted it for now in the code example. If you need it to be called, put it before the return as that is the last thing that will run in your function.

Answer (score 0):

First, to access the length of an array you just have to do

```
myArray = [1, 2, 3];
myArray.length; //3
```

Moreover you have 2 fonctions : initialize and activeTodos where you use this.todos = ...

Without further explanations I assume these variables created with the keyword 'this' inside 2 different functions are out of score.

Verify that your this.todos refers to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need active.Todos() as .length is a built in function by itself.

Just do

Todo's Remaining: {this.todos.length}

Cheers.